# How to Count, Compare and store data in Array for Real Time Data coming in micro seconds from sensors using RxJava 2 Android

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, rx-java2, sensors

```
    fun checkT1Value(eventData: EventData?) 
{


        if(eventData.a == 3.9)
        {

       if(eventData.received_at - Tbuffer_firstReading!! >= 200000)  // This is time Difference condition
      { 

            val alphaValuesArray: DoubleArray = doubleArrayOf(eventData.a)  // Also how to store real time data in Array here
    }
  }
}
```

**(1) I need to Compare values ,do some computation for the data coming in Real time and also store it into Array find the maximum from it.
(2) Also I want to count and display the count in my fragment**

*1)As I am using RxJava 2.I am using Flowable using onBackPressureBuffer and subscribe it then I get eventData.a*

**What is the Problem**

1. I am not able to accuarately Compare, Count or Store in array in Real Time data coming in microseconds.
2. Second problem is my Logs are not coming
3. I am able to see my Count value on fragment which is giving abnormal values. Not counting properly.(This way I know that it is not working properly )
   Also I put toneGenerator inside count . Which triggers abnormally.

*What I think of a solution is using Mathematical operators for Observable/Flowable [Here I think can provide a solution](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#count)*

*Thank you in Advance*

Comment: what kind of sensor do you use? Is sensor API syncronous or asynchronous? did you try solve the problem without RxJava? why do you think RxJava would help?

Comment: My project is already sync with the API and everything works fine . Only one place I got problem